# Automatically fill in SMS passcodes on iPhone in web site

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, sms

iOS can guess the code from the SMS and insert it into the keyboard: https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/automatically-fill-in-sms-passcodes-on-iphone-iphc89a3a3af/ios
This works in my iOS app where the input field is marked as .oneTimePassword.
However, for some reason, this doesn't work on my site. A search on the Internet did not give an understanding of what requirements are imposed on the format of sms messages and/or requirements for input field with code for automatically fill in SMS passcodes on iPhone.

SMS format:

```
Kod dlya podtverzhdeniya zayavki 1234. Esli vi ne oformlyali zayavku, pozvonite nam 1234567890. OrganizationName.
```

For iOS app automatically fill passcode works well, therefore, the problem is in the site markup.

**Maybe someone has encountered and knows how to make the iOS autofill work on the site?**

Comment: Is this problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

you can check out the apple documentation for this feature. If you don't want to read that, then you can accomplish this by explicitly define an input element’s autocompleting value.

in your input field define autocomplete attribute as `one-time-code`

```
example: 
<input id="single-factor-code-text-field" autocomplete="one-time-code"/>
```